# Any benefits of using async html5 APIs with web workers in case we don't expect any callback at all

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, web-worker, html5-filesystem

I have a specific script which

1. Tries to read find some artifacts (binary and text) in local html5 filesystem.
2. If that attempt fails, requesting those artifacts via http
3. Stores all artifacts fetched to, once again, local html5 filesystem

It's also important to note here that results fetched via http are immediately returned to the user, so we actually don't wait till everything will be in filesystem just as expected in optimistic scenario.

Everything works just as expected and my only question is: If I'll use web workers in this very scenario, will a gain something and makes things go faster? Step 3, as you can see, is already asynchronous and we do not wait any kind of response from it. In other words, are there any execution benefits (or/and memory consumption reductions maybe) while using web workers compared with using any browser native asynchronous API *when we don't rely on getting any response from such async triggers*?

Comment: You can't access local storage from a web worker anyway.

Comment: @Pointy, I'm talking about filesystem, not the local storage.

Comment: Ah OK. Well in any case I don't think that a simple situation like what you're describing would benefit from a web worker.

Comment: Nice approach for speedy interface. As for performing step 3 in web worker, though the approach sounds speedy, it might not be. Web workers come with their own overhead in processing, too. It may be that step 3 is so fast on it's own that a worker would just add unnecessary overhead. Contrary to popular notion, workers were not designed to simply have things off-loaded for any reason. Workers are supposed to be used for on-going (e.g., like long polling) processes that would otherwise hang the page if not spun off in a worker. I doubt step 3 really requires that.